# Git post commit mails

Tags: git

Could someone recommend a free git hosting service providing post commit mail notifications which include diff contents?

Answer (score 0):

For a bit of a roundabout solution, a service like [GitHub](http://github.com/) offers an RSS feed of commits and then you can use an RSS to email service like [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/).